# Trying to make a line break with Javascript

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

Trying to get a line break with javascript but its not working.

```
document.getElementById('section').textContent = "Hello world<br>" + msg;
```

I also tried:

```
document.getElementById('section').textContent = "Hello world" + /n msg;
```

Doesn't work either.. am i missing something?

Comment: use .innerHTML instead of .textCotent;

Comment: Read about [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, you're adding literal text, NOT HTML `<br>` elements. You'll either want to set the [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) of the element...

```
document.getElementById('section').innerHTML = "Hello world<br>";
```

...or create text and `<br>` elements and append those to the document.

```
var text = document.createTextNode("Hello world"),
    break = document.createElement("br"),
    section = document.getElementById("section");
section.appendChild(text);
section.appendChild(section);
```